# Question using "Must"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, questions, exam-questions, semi-modals

Can I form a question using this format:
Must + sub. + to + inf.

My teachers said that I could say "must you to drive a car on the right side in England?" as it refers to a law. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use a bare infinitive - one without 'to.'

"Must you drive a car on the right side in England?" is correct.

"Must you to drive..." is incorrect.

If you were to ask, "Must you *learn* to drive a car on the right side in England," then the 'to' form would be correct.

Also note that 'right' can mean not only 'the right side of the road' but also the 'correct' side of the road. In the US the correct side is the right, but in England it is the left.